# On 14.10, nonstop problems trying to get intel i915 and Nvidia 860M to play together

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, 14.10, intel-graphics

I must have spent 3 total days on this, and I keep running in circles.  Essentially I just want to do this:

- Use the intel i915 drivers as the main display drivers
- Have NVidia drivers installed
- Be able to use CUDA.

Earlier I was able to get lucky and get NVidia to be the display driver.  It would lock up once every few minutes, and I had switch to TTY6 then back to TTY7 to get it back.  Then a Ubuntu update happened, and it wouldn't boot to the login prompt.

After hours of trying every option I can think of, I'm trying to start from scratch and remove all NVIDIA stuff and just get it to display in Intel mode.  Just to start from somewhere.

I did a full purge of everything nvidia related, I ran as many reinstall tips as I could find online, and it at least boots and lets me log in.  But once I log in, I get a background wallpaper, a mouse pointer, and nothing else.

Xorg.0.log gives a possibly helpful error:

```
(II) LoadModule: "glx"
...
(EE) failed to load /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so: libnvidia-tls.so.331.113: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on what I can try?  How do I get rid of that nvidia thing still in there?  Is there a way to install glx for the i915 intel drivers?

Answer (score 1):

I spent another day on this, and an answer is pretty straightforward.

- I did a reinstall of Ubuntu, and doing that installed the i915 drivers but not any NVidia drivers.
- I then grabbed the CUDA drivers by downloading the .run file.  I made sure to run it by adding on this command line option:

  ```
  --no-opengl-libs
      Prevents the driver installation from installing NVIDIA's GL libraries.
      Useful for systems where the display is driven by a non-NVIDIA GPU.
      In such systems, NVIDIA's GL libraries could prevent X from loading 
      properly.
  ```

It said it is installing the display driver, but it doesn't appear to do it.  It complains that it had issues with `libGLU.so libX11.so libXi.so libXmu.so libGL.so`.  That's fine, it seems to mean it didn't install the display drivers.

I did a reboot, and I was able to build one of the sample projects and verify it works.  Running `sudo modprobe i915` and `sudo modprobe nvidia` both worked without errors.

What I avoided was trying to install the cuda drivers through `apt-get` or getting updated cuda drivers through the edgers repository. I saw this option recommended often, but it caused me nonstop problems.  At least on this laptop, all Nvidia display drivers through apt-get would have the display hang every few minutes and I'd have to context switch between TTY1 back to TTY7 to get it back.  I could at least use the NVidia prime tool to switch back to the intel driver.  But every time I switched back to intel, `sudo modprobe nvidia` gave errors.  I also struggled to undo many of my setting changes.  Each time one attempt failed, I just reinstalled Ubuntu to start fresh and tried again.

I don't plan on doing heavy graphic gaming on this laptop, so this solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this one 'gingerly'  From my own experience(I have a fairly high-end desktop) if you have an nvidia card installed, you will most likely have not one, but two separate places where you can plug in your monitor(s)  One is for the nvidia card.  The other is for the intel graphics(being a part of your motherboard...does that make sense to you?)  This means plugging your monitor into the nvida port will leave the intel graphics unreachable.  If I am wrong, will someone please correct me on these points?