# Ubuntu with disk encryption doesn't show me encryption password dialog at startup due to i915

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, encryption

I am a "lucky" NVIDIA user with secure boot and TPM enabled. When I used Ubuntu without secure boot, TPM, and disk encryption (previous install), sometimes it worked well, sometimes it didn't, but every time I got it working without problems with NVIDIA.

Right now I need to edit GRUB and set `i915.modeset=0`, because without that I don't see the encryption password dialog.

What could be wrong? How can I fix this?

I have RTX 3070TI and 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i9-12900K × 24

Update: removing `quiet splash` and setting `text` instead for GRUB_DEFAULT_CMDLINE isn't working for me. Only `modprobe.blacklist=i915` or `i915.modeset=0`

Is downloading this module necessary? Do I lose anything when I turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

By this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/597619/on-14-10-nonstop-problems-trying-to-get-intel-i915-and-nvidia-860m-to-play-toge), then my problem would have remained unresolved, everything was fixed without any additional configuration, just when I inserted the hdmi wire into the motherboard connector, that is, the processor ...

If you, like me, have a graphics card built into the processor (iGPU) and two monitors that you connect to the connectors of your NVIDIA card, and for some reason you want the i915 module to be enabled, follow the following steps:

1. Remove `i915.modeset=0` or everything related to disabling the i915 module from `/etc/default/grub`.
2. Run `sudo update-grub` to upgrade `grub` config.
3. Shutdown the PC.
4. Put the second monitor (in my case) to motherboard connector (instead of video card connector).
5. Reboot the PC.

If you don't have a second monitor that can make the i915 work and your system boot successfully, then probably the only way is to disable the module:

1. Just put `i915.modeset=0` or `nomodeset` or `modprobe.blacklist=i915` to your `/etc/default/grub`.
2. Then run `sudo update-grub`.
3. Reboot your PC

Update: Also if you don't disable i915 module disabling from `/etc/default/grub` I'll get unexpected behavior like random Wi-Fi module disabling (in my case) or

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and include the actual steps that you followed to resolve your issue?

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog i finished editing my answer, is it what you expected?

Comment: It's good and thanks for responding to my request! I also did some edits in your post. However. I'm not sure if the first part of your post (*"I understand that [...] that is, the processor ..."*) is actually needed. If it's needed, could you please make it more specific to  the answer? If it's not really needed, could you please remove it? Also, it seems that you haven't completed your last statement...

Comment: @BeastOfCaerbannog sure

Comment: thank you for editing my answer and post, english is not my native language