# Can I find out what's wrong with my boot if I can't boot properly?

Tags: boot, kernel, login, log, debugging

Unfortunately [the issue I'm facing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1483916/ubuntu-with-disk-encryption-doesnt-show-me-encryption-password-dialog-at-startu) has not yet been answered, in regards to this, I would like to know if I can find some logs somewhere or add any parameters to any configs to see what went wrong during my boot without the options described in the thread above?

Comment: `sudo dmesg` shows your boot.

Comment: @Rinzwind But doesn't this command show the logs of the current load, where I have already disabled the modules? I would like to understand what happens when all the modules are enabled and I can't get into the system or even gdm